# Locking entire database while running a delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, delayed-job

My delayed job has something to do with exporting slightly edited version of most of the tables in the app's database, and while doing so, it is critical that none of the current data is being edited.

Is it possible to lock the entire database while running this delayed job?

**More Information:**

The database to be exported is in PostgreSQL, Heroku's postgresql database, to be more specific.

The flow is something like (all below should be done automatically by the code):

1. site would be put in maintenance mode,
2. freeze then export the database, then
3. when exporting is complete, re-activate the site back

Comment: what type of database are you using? MySQL, postgres, or..?

Answer (score 0):

Given there is not a lot of information with your question, I am going to answer you as best I can.

1) What is the database type and model? Is it a standalone DB like MS Access or Informix SE?

2) If not a standalone engine, does this database support replication. I used to work a lot with MS SQL Server, and replication had implications while the database was live and being edited. That is the implications were whether edited data was replicated. In this case, consult the docs. Is it an option to use replication to preserve the current database?

3)  What kind of task is this? It sounds like maintenance. Our Informix SE databases lock when being imported or exported. On the production server, it is my job to make sure no local server applications are trying to access the locked DB, and that our external payments web site cannot interfere while the db is locked.

4) If this is a production site that is not in maintenance mode, then I suggest you probably do not want to lock an entire database.

I am sorry for not answering your question directly, but more information is needed like are you asking if this can be done from the Ruby DB interface on some model of db.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying to this. I have added more information above. Yes this is a maintenance task, see the flow above too.

Comment: If this is maintenance, then lock the DB. By maintenance, I'm assuming nothing else is accessing the DB. You might have to lock the database by not locking the actual DB, if PostgreSQL does not support that, but by blocking access to the DB. I'm not a PostgreSQL expert. I use MySQL.